# SQL: Why does 'Case When' won't work in my code?

Tags: sql, case, bins

Here is my ER Diagram

[image: Yelp Dataset ER Diagram]

I want to categorize the `stars` attribute in `business` table into something like this:

- 2.0 - 3.0 stars = '2-3'
- 4.0 - 5.0 stars = '4-5'
- other           = 'none'

I tried using this code:

```
select case b.stars
when (b.stars >= 2.0 and b.stars <=3.0) then '2-3'
when (b.stars >= 4.0) then '4-5'
else 'none'
end stars_group
from business b
```

But the case when doesn't work in this table, How to solve this?

Comment: `case b.starts` needs to be just `case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the two types of cases.  You want the version with separate conditions:

```
select (case when (b.stars >= 2.0 and b.stars <= 3.0) then '2-3'
             when (b.stars >= 4.0) then '4-5'
             else 'none'
        end) as stars_group
```

If you are just using equality, you can use a *simple case* expression -- but the comparisons need to strict equality:

```
select (case trunc(b.stars)
             when 2 then 'Two'
             when 3 then 'Three'
             else 'none'
        end) as stars_group
```

With inequalities, you need a *searched case* where each `where` clause is evaluated to determine the first `then` that is returned.  The searched case has no expression between `case` and `where`.

Comment: ohh, i get it now. So case 'attribute' can't be used to create a certain range into bins. Thank you for the solution, really appreciate it